# How to reference to struct inside struct

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I have 2 structs that are closely related to each other so i want one struct to reference to the other. Like so:

```
//inside maze.h
typedef struct{
    char * maze;
    int height, length, cols, rows;
} maze_t;

//inside walker.h
typedef struct {
    int row, col, end_row, end_col, dir, origin;
    maze_t * maze;
} walker_t;
```

But here is my problem: When i want to print the string walker->maze->maze i get a segmentation fault. It's a lot of code, but i dont know where i made the mistake. The segmentation fault occurs in the `move_walker` function.

My code:

maze.c:

```
#include "maze.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

/* Incomplete definitions of the maze support function . */
void init_maze(maze_t* maze, FILE * pFile) {

    int result;

    // obtain file size:
    fseek(pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    int lSize, stringPtr;
    lSize= ftell(pFile);
    rewind (pFile);

    // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
    char* string = malloc (sizeof(lSize);
    if (string == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

    // copy the file into the buffer:
    result = fread (string,1,lSize,pFile);
    if (result != lSize) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}

    fclose(pFile);

    maze->maze = malloc (strlen(string) + 1);

    stringPtr = find_letter_in_string('\n', string);
    strcpy(maze->maze, &string[stringPtr+1]);

    maze->rows = atoi(string);

    stringPtr = find_letter_in_string(',', string);
    maze->cols = atoi(&string[stringPtr+1]);

    printf("Maze has %d rows and %d columns \n", maze->rows, maze->cols);

    return;
}
```

walker.h:

```
#include "maze.h"
#include "walker.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"


walker_t* init_walker(maze_t * maze) {

    walker_t* walker = malloc(sizeof(walker_t));

    walker->dir = 0;

    printf("Made room for walker.\n");

    walker->maze = maze;
    locate(maze, 'S',&walker->row, &walker->col);

    printf("Start coordinates: %d, %d.\n", walker->row, walker->col);

    locate(maze, 'E',&walker->end_row, &walker->end_col);

    return walker;
}

int move_walker(walker_t * walker, int row, int col) {

    printf("maze: %s", walker->maze->maze);

    printf("check: %d\n", check_move(walker->maze, row, col));
    if(! check_move(walker->maze, row, col)){
    printf("hello world");
        return 0;
    }
    walker->row = row;
    walker->col = col;
    return 1;
}
```

main.c:

```
maze = malloc( sizeof (maze_t));

FILE * pFile = fopen(argv[1],"r");
if(pFile == NULL){
    printf("No such file!\n");
    return 0;
}

init_maze(maze, pFile);
printf("Scrambled the maze.\n");


walker = init_walker(maze);
printf("Woken the walker.\n");
```

Sorry for spelling mistakes and such, i have dyslexia next to the fact that this is not my native language.

Comment: Where do you allocate memory for the `maze_t` and `walker_t`?

Comment: @Arkku in the functions `init_maze` and `init_walker` in that order in my main function.

Comment: _walker->maze = maze_ you have to allocate memory for walker->maze

Comment: @Abhay Sorry forgot to add some code from main.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least this part is wrong:

```
result = fread (string,1,lSize,pFile);
// …
maze->maze = (char*)malloc (strlen(string) + 1);
```

`fread` does not NUL-terminate `string`, so you can't use `strlen` on it reliably, because it looks for the terminating `'\0'` and thus continues scanning outside your allocated buffer. `result` would actually contain the number of bytes read in this this case, and you could terminate the string using `string[result] = '\0'`, or simply read with `fgets` instead. The `strlen` itself is unnecessary, since you already know the number of bytes read.

In either case you also need to allocate one more byte for the NUL in `string`:

```
char* string = malloc(lSize + 1);
```

The multiplication by `sizeof(char)` (always 1) and the cast to `char *` can also be removed for better style, as shown.